# How to compare values from/between columns in table in Vaadin?

Tags: css, frontend, vaadin, css-tables

I would like to create a table in Vaadin which allow me to compare values of table's cells.
I have got code like below class Stock:

```
public class Stock {
    private String value1;
    private String value2;
    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }
    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }
    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }
    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
    public Stock() {}
    Stock(String value1, String value2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

Class TableView:

```
import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class TableView extends CustomComponent implements View {
    static final String NAME = "Stock table";
    private int prev_value_1 = 0;
    private int prev_value_2 = 0;
    TableView() {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        List<Stock> stock_list = Arrays.asList(
                new Stock("1", "2"),
                new Stock("3", "1"),
                new Stock("2", "3"),
                new Stock("2", "3"),
                new Stock("4", "5"));
        Grid<Stock> grid = new Grid<>();
        grid.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        grid.setItems(stock_list);

        grid
        .addColumn(Stock::getValue1)
        .setCaption("Value1")
        .setStyleGenerator(stockRow -> {
            int int_cur_val_tmp = Integer.parseInt(stockRow.getValue1());
            if(int_cur_val_tmp < prev_value_1){
                prev_value_1 = int_cur_val_tmp;
                return "red";
            }
            else if(int_cur_val_tmp == prev_value_1) {
                prev_value_1 = int_cur_val_tmp;
                return "yellow";
            }
            else {
                prev_value_1 = int_cur_val_tmp;
                return "green";
            }
        });

        grid
        .addColumn(Stock::getValue2)
        .setCaption("Value2")
        .setStyleGenerator(stockRow -> {
            int int_cur_val_tmp = Integer.parseInt(stockRow.getValue2());
            if(int_cur_val_tmp < prev_value_2){
                prev_value_2 = int_cur_val_tmp;
                return "red";
            }
            else if(int_cur_val_tmp == prev_value_2) {
                prev_value_2 = int_cur_val_tmp;
                return "yellow";
            }
            else {
                prev_value_2 = int_cur_val_tmp;
                return "green";
            }
        });

        layout.addComponents(grid);
        setCompositionRoot(layout);
    }
}
```

And styles.scss

```
@import "mytheme.scss";
@import "addons.scss";
.mytheme {
  @include addons;
  @include mytheme;

}
.v-grid-cell.red {
  color: red;
}
.v-grid-cell.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
.v-grid-cell.green {
  color: green;
}
```

This code allow me to compare values between rows in table -> to compare value1 from row 1 with some other value1 from row 2 in the/within SAME/ONE COLUMN and in affect to put a special color. The same for value2 -> compare some value2 from row 1 with value2 from row 2 in the/within SAME/ONE COLUMN.
Right now I would like to compare value1 with value2 which are from another columns and in effect put a special color.
Right now I would like to compare values between columns and based on this put special color.

Do you know if it is possible to do it in Vaadin?

Comment: Aren't you actually then just comparing -say- `Stock.getValue1()` to `Stock.getValue2()` in columns your `StyleGenerator` ? So not columns. And better use - for example - `ListDataProvider` in your `Grid`.

Comment: Generally it is possible, thanks.